# Implement specialised array from Swift protocol in Objective C

Tags: arrays, swift, objective-c

I'd like to implement a String array from a Swift protocol in Objective C. Here's the protocol:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    var myProperty: [String] { get }
}
```

And here's the Objective-C implementation:

```
@interface MyThing : NSObject <MyProtocol>

@property (readonly, copy, nonnull) NSArray* myProperty;

- (_Nonnull instancetype)init;

@end

//

@implementation MyThing

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

- (NSArray*)myProperty {
    return @[@"A value"];
}

@end
```

Note that because it's just an NSArray*, this will resolve with type `[Any]` when used rather than `[String]`. The error becomes apparent when trying to use the `MyThing` class from Swift again, where it's convinced that the property has not been implemented.

Is there a way to hint to the compiler that this is a string array? Or make Swift wrap the `[Any]` array implicitly so it can be used as a `[String]` array?

Otherwise I see two workarounds which are less pleasant:

1. Make a new Swift class that encapsulates a String array and make the property use that instead. The downside to this is that you would have to implement all the array methods in that class if you want the type to work like an array without unboxing it.
2. Make an internal property getter that Objective C can override with an `[Any]` type, and then introduce a convenience property that casts the result to a string. This isn't nice either as it compromises type safety.

Comment: It's been a while since I dealt with Objective-C and might forget something, but I don't follow, is there a reason you don't specify the type of the array in Objective-C? `NSArray<NSString *> *`.

Comment: Well that was embarassingly easy! Thanks @lazarevzubov. I was under the impression that generics were not supported and it would only do type erasure.

Answer (score 0):

Well this was easy! I didn't realise arrays can be typed in Objective-C:

```
@interface MyThing : NSObject <MyProtocol>

@property (readonly, copy, nonnull) NSArray<NSString*>* myProperty;

@end
```